# Dimesion of a subspace subject to linear constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Suppose $X$ is $n\times K$ with full column rank $K$ and $G$ is $q\times K$ with full row rank $q$. If $q<K$, how do I see that $\mathcal{L}\equiv\{Xb,b\in\mathbb{R}^K,Gb=0\}$ has dimension 
>   $K-q$?

Because $X$ has full column rank, its column space can be spanned by $K$ independent column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The constraint $Gb=0$ imposes limits on the coefficients contained in $b$ when we form linear combinations of these $K$ vectors. But I don't know how to proceed formally. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to show that $\text{dim}(X(\text{Ker}(G))) = K-q$. Remember that row rank is equal to column rank, and that by rank nullity, for all linear maps $A$, $\text{dim}(\text{Ker}(A))+\text{rank}(A) = \text{dim}(\text{Dom}(A))$. Use this to show that $X$ is injective, and that $\text{dim}(\text{Ker}(G))=K-q$.

Comment: Thanks. I know the results you refer to in the second sentence but I don't see how they help. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I have added more details

Comment: Thanks again. Please give me some time to digest.